# How to disable filter of a field in Zend Framework 2 in the controller?

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Form to add/edit user I get from service manager with already installed filter, which is the test password. But this password is not needed when the user is edited. Can I somehow disabled password field validation in the controller?

In the getServiceConfig function of the module:

```
// ....
'UserCRUDFilter' => function($sm)
{
    return new \Users\Form\UserCRUDFilter();
},

'UserCRUDForm' => function($sm, $param, $param1)
{
    $form = new \Users\Form\UserCRUDForm();
    $form->setInputFilter($sm->get('UserCRUDFilter'));
    return $form;
},
// ....
```

In the controller I first of all getting a form object from service manager:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserCRUDForm');
```

Then disable user password validation and requirements, when user is edited and password not specified:

```
if ($user_id > 0 && $this->request->getPost('password') == '') {
      $form->.... // Someway gained access to the filter class and change the password field validation
}
```

And after this i make a validation:

```
$form->isValid();
```

Comment: This is the reason for [validation groups](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it!

```
// If user is editted - clear password requirement
if ($user_id > 0) {
    $form->getInputFilter()->get('password')->setRequired(false);
    $form->getInputFilter()->get('confirm_password')->setRequired(false);
}
```

This lines is disables requirement of input form fields :)

Comment: If you believe that you find the correct solution for your problem, please mark your answer as correct.

Comment: foozy, unfortunately i can't. stackoverflow says that only tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

if you like to set all validators by yourself, call inside your form class

`$this->setUseInputFilterDefaults(false);`

to disable auto element validations/filter added from zend.

if you like to remove filter from elements call in your controller after your form object this

`$form->getInputFilter()->remove('InputFilterName');`

Answer (score 0):

`$form->get('password')->removeValidator('VALIDATOR_NAME');` should do the trick.

Note that you may have to iterate trough the Validatorchain when using Fieldsets.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Form\Element::removeValidator()

Comment: this won't work because inputfilter are added below the element classes and belong to the form class

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
        'name'        => 'password',
        'required'    => true,
        'allow_empty' => true,
    ));
```

And on ModeleTable: saveModule:

```
public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
    {
        $data = array(
            'name'        => $album->name,
        );
        if (isset($album->password)){
            $data['password'] = $album->password;
        }
```